# Avoiding infinite template instantiations

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, variadic

Given

```
struct A {};
struct B { using links = std::tuple<A>; };
struct C { using links = std::tuple<A,B>; };
struct D { using links = std::tuple<C>; };
struct E { using links = std::tuple<D>; };
struct F { using links = std::tuple<D>; };
struct G { using links = std::tuple<D>; };
struct H { using links = std::tuple<E,F,G>; };
```

`AllLinksFrom<H>` is to be `std::tuple<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H>` (the order of the letters do not matter) because H is linked to E,F, and G, which are in turn linked to other classes, which in turn are linked to other classes, and so forth, until all links of links of links of ... are obtained and the union taken of all those classes.

I've solved this problem already, but my solution breaks down if I change, say,

```
struct E { using links = std::tuple<D>; };
```

to

```
struct E { using links = std::tuple<D,H>; };
```

because by linking E back to H, I get an infinite recursion (using my current algorithm).  In this case, the output is still supposed to be the same (i.e. `std::tuple<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H>`).  Can someone suggest how to solve this problem?

In case you want to write out a full solution, you can borrow my code for `Union` and `has_links_member` (tested to work correctly) to save time:

```
template <typename T>
struct Identity { using type = T; };

// ExistsInPack
template <typename T, typename Pack> struct ExistsInPack;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class P>
struct ExistsInPack<T, P<>> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct ExistsInPack<T, P<First, Rest...>> : ExistsInPack<T, P<Rest...>> {};

template <typename T, template <typename...> class P, typename... Rest>
struct ExistsInPack<T, P<T, Rest...>> : std::true_type {};

// Union of packs.
template <typename, typename, typename> struct UnionHelper;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types, typename... Accumulated>
struct UnionHelper<P<Types...>, P<>, P<Accumulated...>> {
    using type = P<Accumulated...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Types, typename... Accumulated>
struct UnionHelper<P<Types...>, P<First, Rest...>, P<Accumulated...>> : std::conditional_t<ExistsInPack<First, P<Types...>>::value,
        UnionHelper<P<Types...>, P<Rest...>, P<Accumulated...>>,
        UnionHelper<P<Types...>, P<Rest...>, P<Accumulated..., First>>
    > {};

template <typename...> struct Union;

template <>
struct Union<> { using type = void; };

template <typename Pack>
struct Union<Pack> : Identity<Pack> {};

template <typename Pack1, typename Pack2>
struct Union<Pack1, Pack2> : UnionHelper<Pack1, Pack2, Pack1> {};

template <typename Pack1, typename Pack2, typename... Packs>
struct Union<Pack1, Pack2, Packs...> : Union<typename Union<Pack1, Pack2>::type, Packs...> {};

// Detecting if the member type T::links exists in class T.
template <typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_links_member : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_links_member<T, void_t<typename T::links>> : std::true_type {};

// LinkedTypes<T> is T::links if such a member type exists in T, else it is std::tuple<>.
template <typename T, bool HasLinksMember>
struct LinkedTypesHelper : Identity <typename T::links> {};

template <typename T>
struct LinkedTypesHelper<T, false> : Identity <std::tuple<>> {};

template <typename T>
using LinkedTypes = typename LinkedTypesHelper<T, has_links_member<T>::value>::type;
```

In case you want to see it, here is my current full solution (which works for the first example only):   http://ideone.com/efKFRo

Comment: Just store a list of types you've already visited, and not visit them again?

Comment: Thanks. Solved using your idea and defining a new struct `RelativeComplement`, which takes a pack and removes from it all elements in a second pack.  Full solution here for anyone interested in how it was fixed:  http://ideone.com/WBe4LU